# how to insert data into one-to-many relationship using linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

how to insert data into one-to-many relationship using linq to sql. i have two table first is person and secondly is order ,i have make a relationship between both table,i want to insert data into both table at a time

```
public ActionResult Add(CustomerViewData data)
    {
        string message = "";
        var item = data.Customer;

        try
        {
            _repositoryCustomer.Insert(item);
            _repositoryCustomer.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { message = Constants.RecordSaved, id = item.CustomerId});

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = "Customer had error saving.";
            Log.Error(message, ex);
        }
        return View("Edit", new CustomerViewData { PageMode = PageMode.Add, Message = message });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
  Person p = new Person();
  Order o = new Order();
  p.Orders.Add(o); //connect the objects into an object graph.

  dc.Persons.Add(p); //add the graph to the data context
  dc.SubmitChanges();  //save it all.
}
```

Comment: do you know why doing that, EF understand that I want to create the Orders associated with each Person instead of just relate them?

Comment: 1. EF knows that this Order instance was not loaded, so it assumes that this is a new object that can be saved.
2. EF uses object tracking to save all the related records in the object graph in a single transaction.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/